# Good utility to traverse a directory structure and show me all security permissions?

Tags: windows, permissions, file-management

Is there a good windows utility that will traverse a path (and all subfolders therein) and list the permissions for each folder?

Answer (score 2):

Would this do the job? Microsoft's [SubInACL](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=E8BA3E56-D8FE-4A91-93CF-ED6985E3927B&displaylang=en). It's command-line, but it is free.

> SubInACL is a command-line tool that enables administrators to obtain security information about files, registry keys, and services, and transfer this information from user to user, from local or global group to group, and from domain to domain.

Answer (score 1):

On WinXP, the command-line `cacls` command gets the information you want.  Given only a filename argument, it displays the permissions.

Use GNU `find` to locate and run it on every directory.  You can get `find` the [Cygwin emulation environment](http://www.cygwin.com/) or a win32-port package like [GnuWin32](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/) or [UnxUtils](http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/).

```
> find <path> -type d -exec cacls {} \;
              ^^^^^^^
                 |
                 +----- only matches directories; 
                        use `-type f` for only regular files; 
                        omit for everything
```